# Что за ошибка Метрики при сборке пакета?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, yandex-metrika-api, microsoft-store

Сделал универсальное приложение для магазина Windows, добавил туда `Yandex.Metrika` из `nuget`. В режиме отладки всё нормально, но при сборке пакетов для магазина вываливается ошибка:

> Серьезность Код Описание Проект Файл Строка Ошибка ILT0020: Сборка "Yandex.Metrica, Version=1.6.5415.248, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" содержит тип с пустым именем в пространстве имен или области "{01CB4E05-F6C1-49AE-B906-B21681687}". Пустые имена не допускаются.

Что это значит? Как лечить?

Comment: Поищите на форуме яндекса, перечитайте мануал, проверьте использываете ли вы последнюю версию Yandex.Metrica. А вобще похоже, что проблема здесь: `PublicKeyToken=null`. Когда зарегистрировались в яндекс метрике, вам дадут ключ его сюда нужно подставить (ключ как индитификатор).

Comment: В метрике дают только appid, который надо в xaml вписать, его вписал. Поиск строки PublicKeyToken во всем решении не дает результата. Гугл (и яндекс) о такой ошибке тоже, как ни странно не знает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поддержка метрики сказала, что это их баг. Выпустили новую версию. На исправление у них ушло 2+ месяца.